# Load login page without Sidebar, Navbar and Dashboard in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to load login page without sidebar, navbar and dashboard?

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of putting images

Comment: i added a possible solution for you.  You'll need to do some googling of implementations as syntax varies from place to place.  Let me know if it's any help

Comment: Post your code as text, not an image

Answer (score 4):

extract your `<div id="wrapper">...</div>` into a separate component.

Add a route for your wrapper with no path

```
<Route component={Wrapper} />
```

Wrap all the routes in `<Switch>` from `react-router`.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
    <Route component={Wrapper} />
</Switch>
```

`Switch` will mean that only the first matching route is rendered.

A route with no path will match any path.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a flag in your redux store to determine whether these components should be displayed.

Setup the initial state in your reducer, and have your Sidebar, Navbar, and Dashboard subscribe to that flag and use conditional rendering in each of those components.

So your redux state would maybe have something like:

`showPageContent: false`

In each of your components, have them subscribe by connecting them and passing in a `mapStateToProps` like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  shouldRender: state.showPageContent
})

export default connect(mapeStateToProps)(Sidebar)
```

Then in the render for each of your components:

```
render() {
  this.state.shouldRender ? <Sidebar> : null
}
```

OR

```
render() {
  if (this.state.shouldRender) {
    <Sidebar>
  } 
}
```

You would need to implement an login action that set the `showPageContent` flag to true once logged in successfully.

Example:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Answer (score -1):

Well, I will suggest that you should have separate container for Credentials and Login and Signup should be the components.

That page should have public routing, which means it could be viewed by general public. Your Navbar, Sidebar and Dashboard should be other components and should not be included in Login and Signup components.